# Elasticsearch sync with mysql database using jdbc river

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am trying to synchronize data from my mysql database to an ElasticSearch index. I need to **update the data** in the index as it changes in the database. I am trying **jdbc river** plugin. It gives an option to update the index periodically from **mysql** mentioned in this tutorial [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart).

But instead of replacing the values that changed, it adds new entries only.
I need the new values only to exist in my index and the old values to be replaced.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please ask for more details if the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that you get back _id field from your SQL request as described [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Labeled-columns).

Comment: _id is generated by Elastic search in my case. I am not able to understand how labeling would help in my problem. Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem although partially. Need to set **autocommit** to **true** to reflect the updates.

Comment: _id is autogenerated if you don't provide it I guess. _id is used then for updating or deleting documents.

Comment: yes. I was able to figure that out. You are correct about the _id field.